# bind keyboard linux ubuntu

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, autokey

In windows, I used autohotkey to this work:

When I press <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> it returns <kbd>↑</kbd>. 
When I press <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> it returns <kbd>↓</kbd>. 
When I press <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> it returns <kbd>←</kbd>. 
When I press <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> it returns <kbd>→</kbd>. 
When I press <kbd>J</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> it returns <kbd>⌫</kbd>.

And when I press <kbd>J</kbd> and release, it then returns the <kbd>J</kbd> key.

Can I do the same in Ubuntu GNOME?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with ubuntu gnome tweak I disabled capslock and set hyper button on it.
after that with autokey application I set some shortcut.
now :

if I push <kbd>capslock</kbd> and <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>↑</kbd> will push
if I push <kbd>capslock</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>↓</kbd> will push
if I push <kbd>capslock</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd> will push
if I push <kbd>capslock</kbd> and <kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd> will push
if I push <kbd>capslock</kbd> and <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>end</kbd> will push
if I push <kbd>capslock</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>home</kbd> will push
if I push <kbd>capslock</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>, <kbd>enter</kbd> will push

if you have good experience about using autokey , or you know better shortcuts, share it